# Is it recommended to update grains using custom execution module

Tags: salt-stack

I am new to salt and currently I am working on a custom execution module that returns the list of customers on a specific production environment. I was thinking of adding it to the grains using the API.
My question is that a good practice, if not is there a better way of adding it to the grains?

Comment: No one can give a better recommendation than the official documentation. Have you seen the official documentation on [grains](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/grains/)? Especially the "WHEN TO USE A CUSTOM GRAIN" section.

Comment: Thank you @seshadri_c, I will take an in-depth look at pillars as possible destination to my data.